# Is there a policy that can limit the growth of an AWS S3 buckets total size?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

We have an AWS S3 bucket that accepts uploads from untrusted sources which are then processed and moved out of the bucket.

Is there a Policy that can limit the growth of the bucket to some predetermined upper bound to protect us in case something goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I know.

You can create [**Billing alerts**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html) to get notifications when AWS thinks that your monthly spend may be over a given threshold.

Answer (score 1):

There's not such a policy as far as I know.

That being said, you could trigger a lambda and then make this lambda check the properties of your bucket and then you would perform any actions you need.